# How to return an empty json array from an empty resultset. Postgres 9.5+

Tags: postgresql

I try to return an empty array [] when i find no entries in my db but i return [{}]. How i can only return [] on empty result set ?

```
const getUserProfile = (identifier, value) => {
    return db.oneOrNone (`
    select 
    p.username,
    array_to_json(array_agg(json_strip_nulls(json_build_object('index', pp.index, 'filename', pp.filename)))) as pictures
    from person p
    left join (select person_id, index, filename from person_picture order by index) pp on p.person_id = pp.person_id
    where upper(cast(p.$1~ as text)) = upper(cast($2 as text))
    group by p.person_id`, [ identifier, value ])
}
```

I try this:

```
coalesce(array_to_json(array_agg(json_strip_nulls(json_build_object('index', pp.index, 'filename', pp.filename)))), '[]') as pictures
```

but it does not work too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just is a `CASE` expression to check the `LEFT JOIN`'ed data for emptiness (`MAX(pp.index) IS NULL` does that in this case with minimal overhead:

```sql
SELECT
  p.username, 
  CASE
    WHEN max(pp.index) IS NOT NULL THEN
      array_to_json(array_agg(json_strip_nulls(json_build_object('index', pp.index, 'filename', pp.filename))))
    ELSE
      '[]'::json
  END as pictures
FROM t_person p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT person_id, index, filename FROM t_person_picture ORDER BY index) pp ON p.person_id = pp.person_id
GROUP BY p.username;
```

Full example: https://rextester.com/YSNM89392